# PHP regex - find matches not between specific tags

Tags: php, regex

Here is an example of string I want to parse with PHP regular expressions:

```
this is first %@ variable <bpt>inside tags %@ variable</bpt> trailing %@ variable
```

What I need to match is `%@` sequence NOT between `<bpt>` and `</bpt>`. So for this string pattern should return 2 matches.

This is what I have so far:

```
%@(?!(?!<bpt).*\/bpt)
```

It doesn't work as expected and returns only last appearance of the `%@`. In regex pattern I want to check that there is no `</bpt>` closing tag after the match, but case of the `<bpt> ... </bpt>` after match should be allowed.

[Link to regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/k2n42N/1/)

Comment: What qualifies as the "%@ sequence"? is it just the "%@" and the following word? Can you wipe out the tags and what's in them altogether and just try to do a regex on what remains?

Comment: @dgig hello. yes, "%@ sequence" is literally  "%@". I will think about this approach, but my final goal is to replace "%@" with some other string. So if I wipe out the tags I will need to find a way to compile string back somehow.

Comment: Aha, I see. That still may be easier really (though may need another step) - just replace it with a simple string like `***` and it is easily found again and replaced. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your regex a little bit:

```
(?s)%@(?!(?:(?!<bpt>).)*<\/bpt>)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/NDBXS9/1)

Breakdown:

```
(?s) # Enable DOTALL flag
%@ # Match `%@`
(?! # A negative lookahead that means preceding match
    # shouldn't come with next patterns which say:
    (?:(?!<bpt>).)* # Without matching `<bpt>`
    <\/bpt> # Match `</bpt>`
) # End of lookahead
```

But there is also a more optimal approach. Since PHP (PCRE) is being used, you could use a backtracking verb named `SKIP`:

```
<bpt>.*?<\/bpt>(*SKIP)(*F)|%@
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/NAh48E/1)

This way you match an entire `bpt` tag (asap) then tell engine to skip over and try another path.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, **check the comments for explanation**

```
$str="this is first %@ variable1 <bpt>inside tags %@ variable</bpt> trailing %@ variable2 %@";
//strip put all contents inside <bpt>
$content = preg_replace('/<bpt>[^<]+<\/bpt>/i', '', $str);
//split string to words 
$arr=explode(" ",$content);
//use array map for condition
//check for %@ and return preceding element after that 
$variable_only=array_map(function ($a,$k)use($arr) { if($a==='%@') {return isset($arr[$k+1]) ? $arr[$k+1] :'' ; } }, $arr,array_keys($arr));
//remove blank arrays and reset keys
$variable_only=array_values(array_filter($variable_only));
print_r($variable_only);
```

output

```
Array ( [0] => variable1 [1] => variable2 )
```